# How to find corrupt page in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, corruption

I know I can execute a `DBCC CHECKDB` and get a status of my database.

Questions

- How can I find if there is some corrupt data page into my database?
- If an error is throwndue to page corruption, where can I find which pages are corrupt?
- How can can I find out the page number of each corrupt page.

Can anybody can tell me where to find those page ids ?

Comment: I think that i found the table where the corrupt page id are stored. Can it be 'suspect_pages' of the MSDB database ?

Comment: yes there is a possiblity to have a msdb database corrupted pages. MSDB stores info about backups, restores, all jobs info. If SQL is forcebly stopped or another failure event occurs when a backup, restore or job is changing the data of some page - then this page can become corrupted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is a suspect_pages table.

Here is more good info on DBCC CHECKDB [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cindygross/dbcc-checkdb-database-integrity)